# Must I save a record after creating it to save it in SQLITE with Gorm?

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I’m using a SQLITE database with Gorm and need to save a new record.

The problem I have is that when I create a record and restart the program, the record is not found in the database. Is saving the record required after creating it ?

[The example program given in the Gorm documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/index.html) doesn’t save the record.

Comment: *"Must I save a record after creating it to save it in SQLITE with Gorm?"* -- Nope. You are either not successfully creating a record (did you check the error after Create?), or you are not creating what you think you are and because of that you are trying to retrieve something else. Or you are using a manual transaction without Committing. Perhaps, if you'd like more concrete help, consider sharing the code that's not working for you.

Comment: @mkopriva I do check the error on the create operation and there are none. I didn’t specify that I don’t use manual transaction. I don’t do any transaction. I assumed that gorm or sqlite take care of it. How can I ensure that my record is saved in the database ? I see that some records of other tables are saved. I’ll do a minimal example to reproduce the problem and provide with my question.

Comment: I've tested on my machine plain `First` call, if not found then `Create`. Ran the program once, `Create` was called. Ran the program second time, `First` was successful and `Create` was *not* called anymore. So in a default setting `Create` works as one would expect. If you manage to create a [mcve], I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you very much for your help. This proves that my assumption is correct. So there must be a bug in my code. If you provide this as an answer, I’ll validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `Save` a record that you've passed to `Create` already.

You can test this by running the following:

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code  string
    Price uint
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})

    var product Product
    if db.First(&product).Error == gorm.ErrRecordNotFound {
        fmt.Println("no product record, creating now...")
        db.Create(&Product{Code: "D42", Price: 100})
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("product record found: %v", product)
    }
}
```

```
go run main.go
no product record, creating now...
```

```
go run main.go
product record found: { ... }
```